# Why does Renegade Freighter not just have trample?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The artifact vehicle [Renegade Freighter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRenegade%20Freighter%5d) has the ability

> Whenever Renegade Freighter attacks, it gets +1/+1 and gains trample until end of turn.

Given that trample is only generally relevant when attacking, this should behave basically identically to:

> Trample
>
> Whenever Renegade Freighter attacks, it gets +1/+1 until end of turn.

At first, I thought that maybe this was because it would be strange to have a non-creature have trample, so it only gets trample at a time that it is a creature. But then I saw [Fleetwheel Cruiser](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFleetwheel%20Cruiser%5d), which is another vehicle that does always have trample. In fact, [Untethered Express](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUntethered%20Express%5d) is even more similar, in that it does have a when-attack ability, yet it also just always has Trample.

Renegade Freighter could be seen as slightly weaker as worded, because something like [Stifle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStifle%5d) could prevent it from getting Trample. However, that seems like a small enough thing that it wouldn't be specifically designed around.

Is it known why this card only gets trample when it attacks? A good answer could either point to any statements about it from the development team, or to information about general templating choices where this is a consistent design choice. Or finally, perhaps there is an important difference between always having trample vs only having trample when attacking that I am missing.

Comment: Question: are there any Vehicles from that set *or earlier* which have properties like first strike or trample?  (Maybe they where just avoiding having non-creature artifacts with trample that early on in the Vehicle mechanic?  Or a design left over from even earlier in Vehicle design?)

Comment: @Yakk Fleetwheel Cruiser was mentioned in the question as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renegade Freighter is a Common.  The Head Designer of Magic has stated twice ten years apart that a Common should only have one ability, I don't recall any posts where he ever recanted the position:

https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/common-courtesy-2002-06-10

https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/common-knowledge-2011-04-18

> Your card should do one thing. If it's a creature, just give it one
>   ability, whether that's a keyword, activated ability or a triggered
>   ability.

Clearly 'Crew' got a pass on that rule for this set; but it is otherwise adhered to among the Common vehicles.  It seems like a feasible claim that the designer of this card was just being "clever" in "only having one ability."

Answer (score 14):

There are some more relevant edge cases where the difference actually matters. Two of the cards that were in standard at the same time as Renegade Freighter were [Odric, Lunarch Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOdric%2c%20Lunarch%20Marshal%5d) and [Majestic Myriarch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMajestic%20Myriarch%5d). Both of those check for abilities including Trample at the beginning of combat, so in both cases, they can find Trample on Untethered Express, but not on Renegade Freighter.

Comment: [Stifle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=true&multiverseid=46558) would also like to have a say. Because trample is part of the triggered ability, stifle can stop it (although I would at least consider stifling the crewing instead).

Comment: Do you think it's likely that they actually did this to make Renegade Freighter very slightly weaker though?

Comment: Ah, the great mysteries of Magic's R&D crew.

Comment: I suspect that this is the correct answer, though if you want to know for sure you can always try [Blogatog](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/).

Answer (score 10):

I'd say the most likely reason is space in the textbox. "Trample" would have required an additional line of rules text (since abilities like that get their own line), which seems like it would have a hard time fitting in.

Comment: If they wanted to fit more lines, they could've skipped the reminder text on Crew. So that's not really a problem, I think.

Comment: Skipping reminder text on a new mechanic on *a common* is a big problem.

Comment: @Bakabaka Fair enough. Didn't look at the rarity and set.

Comment: But Untethered Express seems to have the same amount of text. In fact, it looks like the reminder text on Untethered Express is actually smaller in order to fit on less lines.

Comment: @GendoIkari Untethered Express is an uncommon, as opposed to a common, and it's in the second set that had vehicles after their introduction. I guess that's legit ground for reducing the type size by a point :) For added irony, read the Express's flavour text.

Comment: You don't always have reminder text with trample, though.